# ToDictionary how can i find the duplicate key

Tags: c#

I want to correct the database but I can't find the duplicate object. Is there a way for me to find the key that is having problems?

> "An item with the same key has already been added."}

```
    try
    {
        var dict = new SortedDictionary<long, long>(ReturnGetReviewTemplates.ToDictionary(tuple => tuple.Item1.Id, tuple => tuple.Item2.ReviewId));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        string error = e.InnerException.Message;
    }
```

Comment: List your `tuple.Item1.Id`s?

Comment: Yes I did try that but there is about 2000 rows

Comment: Instead of `ToDictionary`, iterate through `ReturnGetReviewTemplates` with a `foreach` loop. Use `dict.ContainsKey` to check if the key already exists. If it does not, add it. Otherwise, throw an `Exception` containing the key in the message. Or output it. Or whatever you need to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use GroupBy and inspect groups larger than 1:

```
var dupes = ReturnGetReviewTemplates
               .GroupBy(t => t.Item1.Id)
               .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
               .Select(g => g.Key)
               .ToArray();
```

set breakpoint or write a string to Output

```
Debug.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", dupes));
```